# Autoincrement Id in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

Im looking for a way to give my list-objects an Id that autoincrements from 1 to (however many).

This is the class I use

```
public class Movie
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
}
```

I will use this as a list like so:

```
 public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
```

Now lets say that the list contains 10 movies and I delete movie with id 5. I would like the id´s on all movies to change so that the movie that used to have id 6 now has id 5. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You usually don't want to change IDs because it is an identifier that other resources point to. When you change that, the relation changes to a different movie. If you're sure you do want to change it, show the code how you store, read and delete items in your list.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a wrapper for your movies list and letting that class handle the Ids?

```
public class MoviesList
{
    public List<Movie> Movies;

    public MoviesList()
    {
        Movies=new List<Movie>();
    }

    public void Add(Movie movie)
    {
        var highestId = Movies.Any() ? Movies.Max(x => x.Id) : 1;
        movie.Id = highestId + 1;
        Movies.Add(movie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably best to inherit from List<Movie>, then override the add/remove methods, and indexing operator would be perfect

Comment: Thank you! I´ll have a look at this!

Answer (score 1):

This may be simplistic, but why not use the index of the List itself as the id? It would work nicely for the scenario you describe. Then you don't need an `Id` property inside the `Movie` class.

If you have a more complex case which you haven't described, you may need to implement something like a reference counter to keep track of all the `Movie` life-cycles.

Comment: Thats exactly what i would like to do, use the index as Id, but how do I do that?
Can i pas the index as a parameter in this actionlink?
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Home", new { id = Model.Movie[i].Id }

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like your custom collection  with `Add` and `Remove` methods. In this way, you also don't need to specify `ID` while adding new item to your list.

```
public class Movies
{
    public List<Movie> List { get; set; }

    public Movies()
    {
        List = new List<Movie>();
    }

    public void Add(Movie newMovie)
    {
        newMovie.Id = List.Count > 0 ? List.Max(x => x.Id)+1 : 1;
        List.Add(newMovie);
    }

    public void Remove(Movie oldMovie)
    {
        List.Remove(oldMovie);
        List.ForEach((x) => { if (x.Id > oldMovie.Id) x.Id = x.Id - 1; });
    }
}
```

And for testing purposes:

```
Movies movies = new Movies();

movies.Add(new Movie() { Director = "first", Title = "first" });
movies.Add(new Movie() { Director = "second", Title = "second" });
movies.Add(new Movie() { Director = "third", Title = "third" });
movies.Add(new Movie() { Director = "fourth", Title = "fourth" });
movies.Add(new Movie() { Director = "fifth", Title = "fifth" });

movies.Remove(movies.List[3]);
```

Comment: Thank you!
But where would I put this code, in the constructor?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time! I will try!

Answer (score 0):

I would inherit from the `List<Movie>` object and override it's base add/remove functions, incrementing and reseeding the value on add/delete, using the index of the list as a base for the id, something like this (not really tested) -

```
    public class MovieList : List<Movie>
    {
        public new void Add(Movie m)
        {
            base.Add(m);
            m.Id = this.IndexOf(m);
        }
        public new void Remove(Movie m)
        {
            base.Remove(m);
            m.Id = -1;
            Reseed();
        }
        public new void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            Movie m  = this[index];
            this.Remove(m);
        }
        public new int RemoveAll(Predicate<Movie> match)
        {
            List<Movie> removing = new List<Movie>();
            foreach (Movie m in this)
                if (match(m))
                    removing.Add(m);

            foreach (Movie m in removing)
            {
                this.Remove(m);
            }
            return removing.Count;
        }
        public new void RemoveRange(int index, int count)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < count; i++)
            {
                Movie m = this[i];
                this.Remove(m);
            }
        }
        public new Movie this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return base[index];
            }
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
                Reseed();
            }
        }

        private void Reseed()
        {
            foreach (Movie x in this)
            {
                x.Id = this.IndexOf(x);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Movie
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best of way of having Auto Generated Id in C# code is below.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

So whenever you create an object of Employee class it will assign an Unique GUID to ID property so no need to do anything else.